# Allow only one of the many modal dialog to be open at a time in React

Tags: reactjs

I try to create a small bug tracking app with React 17. I have BugComponent where users can easily set priority, status, system, and some other properties by clicking on the related icon and select the value from a small popup dialog. It means I have 5-6 small modal dialogs for each bug and I have 20 bugs by default on the page.

With my current implementation, I have a component for displaying and changing priority like this:

```
export const PrioritySelector = ({priority}) => {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [prio, setPrio] = useState(priority);

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    }

    const handleOnSelect = (selectedPriority) => {
        setPrio(selectedPriority);
        setOpen(false);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <PriorityIcon priority={prio} onClick={handleOnClick} />
            <PriorityOptionSelector open={open} onSelect={handleOnSelect} originalValue={prio}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I also have similar selectors for status and plannedEndDate.

The main `BugComponent` looks like this:

```
export const BugComponent = ({bug}) => {

    return (
        <div className="bug">
            <StatusSelector status={bug.status} />
            <div>{bug.text}</div>
            <PrioritySelector priority={bug.priority} />
            <DateSelector plannedEndDate={bug.plannedEndDate} />
            <CommentIcon numberOfComments={bug.commentCount} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

It works, but the problem is the following:
If I open the dialog with clicking on the icon and then click on other icon of the same bug or even another bug without selecting a value then this modal dialog remains open. So it can happen that a lot of dialogs are open at a time.

[image]

Using vanilla JavaScript I would write something like this before open the new dialog:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.modal-selector.open').classList.remove('open');
```

How can I close dialogs before opening a new one in React?

Comment: Are there always only at most one PrioritySelector that can be open?

Comment: Always only at most one Selector can be open. So if the user clicks on the StatusSelector then the PrioritySelector should be closed.

Comment: I think you need an array of each priorityselector's state to handle it. or you can write your own modal provider to handle it. see this: https://codesandbox.io/s/dialogprovider-bz1j1?file=/src/DialogProvider.tsx

Comment: @Vmxes , is the value `priority` a unique value for each one?

Comment: @hellogoodnight The `priority` can be just Low/Normal/High for any bug entity.

Comment: @Vmxes How do you separate them? Do they have unique id:s, names, values etc?

Comment: @hellogoodnight The `BugComponent` has it's unique id. The `handleOnSelect` method should update the BugComponent but that code is still missing.

Comment: @Vmxes In the BugComponent, how does the individual PrioritySelector differ from each other?

Comment: @hellogoodnight I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: @Vmxes is StatusSelector, PrioritySelector, DateSelector etc all modals?

Comment: @hellogoodnight All looks similar. An icon is shown by default and if you click on it then a small modal/popover/tooltip with possible values is displayed.

Comment: You can close the popup dialog when the user clicks outside the popup

Comment: @AbhaySehgal: Yes, but how? How do I know which component has which popup open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep the information about what modal is currently open in a state variable above the BugComponent.

Do a state variable like this:

```
const NO_MODAL_EXPANDED = {bugId: "", componentType: ""};
const [expandedItem, setExpandedItem] = useState(NO_MODAL_EXPANDED);
    
    // Then you pass these props down to the BugComponent:
<BugComponent
  bug={bug}
  hasExpandedItem={expandedItem.bugId === bug.bugId}
  expandedItemType={expandedItem.componentType}
  setExpandedItem={setExpandedItem}
  closeModal={() => setExpandedItem(NoModalExpanded)}
/>;
```

In BugComponent you do:

```
export const BugComponent = ({
  bug,
  hasExpandedItem,
  expandedItemType,
  setExpandedItem,
  closeModal
}) => {
  const isExpanded = (name) => hasExpandedItem && expanedItemType === name;
  return (
    <div className="bug">
      <StatusSelector
        status={bug.status}
        isExpanded={isExpanded("status")}
        closeModal={closeModal}
        expandItem={() => setExpandedItem({bugId: bug.bugId, componentType: "status"})}
      />
      <div>{bug.text}</div>
      <PrioritySelector
        priority={bug.priority}
        isExpanded={isExpanded("priority")}
        closeModal={closeModal}
        expandItem={() => setExpandedItem({bugId: bug.bugId, componentType: "priority"})}
      />
      <DateSelector
        plannedEndDate={bug.plannedEndDate}
        isExpanded={isExpanded("date")}
        closeModal={closeModal}
        expandItem={() => setExpandedItem({bugId: bug.bugId, componentType: "date"})}
      />
      <CommentIcon
        numberOfComments={bug.commentCount}
        isExpanded={isExpanded("comment")}
        closeModal={closeModal}
        expandItem={() => setExpandedItem({bugId: bug.bugId, componentType: "comment"})}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And in the modal components you do:

```
export const PrioritySelector = ({
  priority,
  isExpanded,
  expandItem,
  closeItem,
}) => {
  const [prio, setPrio] = useState(priority);

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    if (isExpanded) {
      closeItem();
    } else {
      expandItem();
    }
  };

  const handleOnSelect = (selectedPriority) => {
    setPrio(selectedPriority);
    closeItem();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <PriorityIcon priority={prio} onClick={handleOnClick} />
      <PriorityOptionSelector
        open={isExpanded}
        onSelect={handleOnSelect}
        originalValue={priority}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Read through it and see if you understand it. The core thing you need to understand is: you want to express the state in as few variables as possible. The only thing you want to know is: what component, if any, is expanded? Instead of distributing this state over a lot of components, you keep the state in the parent component that is the smallest common denominator.

Comment: Thanks, I got the point and it works fine! As a React newbie, I'm just wondering what if I used Context.

Comment: Sure, you can use Context or redux instead of passing down the props.